# XmlHttpRequest status = 0 on remote server, status 200 on localhost

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache, xmlhttprequest

I have two nearly identical PHP proxy scripts that I call through nearly identical JS. The first works fine in all scenarios.

The second (code below) works on my localhost IIS server in both Firefox and Chrome. On the remote <strike>Glassfish</strike> Apache server, it works in Firefox, but returns `status = 0` with empty return in Chrome (tested in v22 & v26). The two PHP proxy scripts are virtually identical and download similar length data (between 1 and 4 MB). With the following JS, the else and onerror alerts are both triggered.

```
var dateQueryText = interviewDays[exitDay];
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4){
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200){
            var xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
            processGPX(xmlDoc);
        }
        else{alert("Download of GPS data failed for date " + dateQueryText + " Status: " + xmlhttp.status);} 
    }
}
xmlhttp.onerror = function (e){alert("Error encountered and download of GPS data failed for date " + dateQueryText + " Status: " + xmlhttp.status);};

xmlhttp.open("POST","proxy2.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
params = ("case=" + caseID + "&gps=true" + "&date=" + dateQueryText);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

I've tried the following to no avail:

- `async` & `synchronous` downloads
- overriding the `return` type, since GPX (GPS data in XML format) isn't always understood by servers `{xmlhttp.overrideMimeType("text/xml");}`.
- providing the full path to the PHP script

What could be causing the problem in Chrome?

EDIT: Here is the request header for the failing PHP request. There is no response received.

```
Request URL: https://www.XXX.edu/AAA/BBB/CCC/proxy2.php

Request Headers
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:https://www.XXX.edu
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://www.XXX.edu/AAA/BBB/CCC/exitgraphic.php?case=TESTCASE&instrument=0001&mode=TEST
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.10 Chromium/22.0.1229.94 Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4

Form Data
case:TESTCASE
inst:0001
mode:TEST
gps:true
date:02222013
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-try the failing request with Chrome's Developer Tools (Tools --> Developer Tools) activated and post here the headers of the request and the response (in the Network tab), and any error message in the Console tab?

Comment: Added request headers above. No response was received. With the JS as above, I can't figure out what the actual error is, because the e object in xmlhttp.onerror is of XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent type.

Comment: When I switch it to synchronous mode, I get "NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101" stack: "Error: A network error occurred in synchronous requests.

Comment: Is this a cross domain request? If so, you probably need to add support for [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) to your server.

Comment: Same domain. The proxy script is in the same directory as the requesting URL.